# MySQL FULLTEXT search returns only exact match

Tags: mysql

I added a FULLTEXT index to a table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD FULLTEXT(name, descrip, notes);
```

The TEST table has 100 rows. I updated the `descrip` column with 'branch' in one row and 'Branches' in another row.

Then I run

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE MATCH(name, descrip, notes) AGAINST ('branch' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The result returned only rows that contain 'branch'. 'Branches' is not included in the result, even though it is comprised of the word that was searched. How to include 'Branches'? I want to avoid using `LIKE`.

Comment: I'm not sure that full text search works with substrings.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean mode you can use a wildcard:

```
AGAINST ('branch*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your query. You need to use wildcard.

`SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE MATCH(name, descrip, notes) AGAINST ('branch*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`;